# Why radius of power series is defined as $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n)^{1/n} = 1/R$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I am reading definition of radius of convergence of power series $a_nx^{n}$ as $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (|a_n|)^{1/n} = 1/R$.

I cannot understand it intutively, it makes no sense to me. Can anyone explain about this and also they have put a bar on limit. Please someone clarify me what is going on?

Thnaks

Comment: That's not a definition, its a theorem. (You want $|a_n|^{1/n}.$)

Comment: @zhw.can you explain about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius of convergence of
$f(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$
is defined as the value $r$
such that
$f(x)$ converges for
$|x| < r$
and diverges for
$|x| > r$.

As zhw said in a comment,
it is a *theorem* that follows from the definition
that,
if
$\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} = 1/R$,
then $R$ is the radius of convergence.

Comment: why is there a bar above the limit?

Comment: That's the $\limsup.$ You should fix your post to put in absolute values and the $\limsup.$

Comment: @zhw.why is that used here in limits. when doing infinite series i never used lim sup when applying root test, so why is used here? thanks

Comment: Because it is needed for the general result. Suppose $a_n = n, n$ even , $a_n = 1/2^n, n$ odd. Then $\lim a_n^{1/n}$ doesn't exist, but the $\limsup a_n$ does, giving $R=1.$

Comment: @TaylorTed, have you taken a real analysis (not just calculus) class? If not, then that explains why you have not seen the lim sup concept before. It is a more subtle idea than a limit, and frankly in practice it is often not needed, but to have a truly general radius of convergence formula you must use lim sup instead of limits. The series that illustrate this are not really the type you meet unless you are a mathematician. For example, the series in the previous comment will look strange to a non-mathematician and would not normally be met in precisely the way it's presented there.

Comment: The series given by zhw is not totally weird: $\sum a_nx^n$ turns out to be a rational function, but if you met it as a rational function first then it'd be clearer what the radius of convergence of its power series is.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n x^n$ be a power series, and set $R$ as above. Then, if $|x|>R$ it implies that $f(x)$ diverges. Conversely, if $|x|<R$ then it converges. Notice that if $|x|=R$ then you don't know the behaviour of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the power series

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n (x-c)^n}.
\end{align}

Define

\begin{align}
R &= \frac{1}{\limsup_{n \to \infty}{|a_n|^{1/n}}}.
\end{align}

So,

\begin{align}
\limsup_{n \to \infty}{|a_n|^{1/n}} &= \frac{1}{R}.
\end{align}

We note

\begin{align}
\limsup_{n \to \infty}(|a_n (x - c)^n|)^{1/n} &= |x-c| \limsup_{n \to \infty}{|a_n|^{1/n}} \\
&= \frac{|x-c|}{R}.
\end{align}

By the root test, the power series converges if $|x-c| < R$ and the power series diverges if $|x-c| > R$.